# Problema com as urls e views dentro do servidor

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

Estava estudando python e django, e resolvi fazer o site do meu casamento em django. O projeto roda perfeitamente no meu pc local, o problema é quando eu faço o deploy no digital ocean e ele da esse erro aqui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O admin funciona certinho. O problema é a página principal ou qualquer outra pagina que eu tento acessar do meu site.

**Meu urls.py principal:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [ url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
                url(r'', include('casamento.urls'))] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**urls.py do app casamento:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.tela_inicial),
    url(r'^local', views.local_casamento),
    url(r'^listapresentes', views.listapresentes),
    url(r'^presenca', views.presenca),
]
```

Já procurei esse erro no google e nenhuma das soluções funcionaram :(

Comment: Vocês está usando Nginx? E qual a linha de comando que você usa pra iniciar sua app, ex.: `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Era a versão do django. Estava usando a versão 1.10 que vem como padrão pip install django. instalei a versão 1.9 e funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Recomendo você postar uma resposta a sua própria pergunta, de forma a ajudar outras pessoas que possam encontrar o mesmo problema. Você pode fazer isso quando tiver 15 ou mais pontos de reputação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Era a versão do django. Estava usando a versão 1.10 que vem como padrão pip install django. instalei a versão 1.9 e funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.